# Behat/Mink/PageObjects - page object class not found

Tags: behat, mink, pageobjects

Setting up testing with behat for my project... I got most of the things working - except the page objects.  Here's my behat.yml

```
default:
  autoload: [%paths.base%/boostrap]
  suites:
    web:
      paths: [%paths.base%/features/web]
      contexts:
        - Web\LoginContext
    api:
      paths: [%paths.base%/features/api]
      contexts:
        - Api\ApiContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://my.url.com
      selenium2: ~
    SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension:
      namespaces:
        page: [Page]
        element: [Page\Element]
```

I am following the [PageObjectExtention documentation](http://behat-page-object-extension.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I have created `LoginPage` class, which extends from `Page` and updated my context file to use page injection.

My LoginPage class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Page;

use SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\PageObject\Page;

class LoginPage extends Page
{

}
```

and my Context file looks like this:

```
namespace Web;

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Page\LoginPage;

class LoginContext extends MednavMinkContext
{
    private $loginPage;

    public function __construct(LoginPage $homepage)
    {
        $this->loginPage = $homepage;
    }

    ...
}
```

Yet, when I try to run it, I get

```
[ReflectionException]                
Class Page\LoginPage does not exist
```

Where should these page objects be stored?  I tried all possible locations - under `Page` inside boostrap, under `Page` in the root, and a couple of other - no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually resolved the issue, using the `autoload` section in my `composer.json`, which now looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "3.*@stable",
        "behat/mink": "1.6.*@stable",
        "behat/mink-extension": "@stable",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "@stable",
        "sensiolabs/behat-page-object-extension": "@stable"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "@stable",
        "bossa/phpspec2-expect": "@stable"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "lib/"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, inside my lib directory, I have the usual directory structure based on namespaces:

```
lib/
    MyCompany/
        Util/
        Page/
        Config/
```

and so on.  Finally, in my `behat.yml` file, I specify the namespace for the page objects:

```
SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension:
  namespaces:
    page: [MyCompany\Page]
    element: [MyCompany\Page\Element]
```

Answer (score 0):

the following structure should help you:

- tests/bootstrap -> here store all your *Context.php files
- tests/bootstrap/Page -> here store all your *Page.php files

All the page files should be namespaced with `namespace Page;`

The documentation says [here](http://behat-page-object-extension.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html):

> If you use namespaces with Behat, we’ll try to guess the location of
>   your page objects. The convention is to store pages in the Page
>   directory located in the same place where your context files are.

So for example you have

> RegisterPage.php

```
<?php

namespace Page;

use SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\PageObject\Page;

/**
 * Class RegisterPage
 * @package Page
 */
class RegisterPage extends Page
{
    protected $path = '/register/';

}
```

and your Context:

> RegisterContext.php

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\Context\PageObjectContext;

/**
 * Class RegisterContext
 */
class RegisterContext extends PageObjectContext implements Context
{
    /**
     * @Given /^I want to register a new account$/
     */
    public function iWantToRegisterNewAccount()
    {
        $this->getPage('Register Page')->open();
    }
}
```

and finally your definition:

> behat.yml

```
...

extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~

    SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension:
        namespaces:
            page:
                - Page

...

suites:
        account:
            paths:
                - %paths.base%/tests/behat/features/account
            contexts:
                - FixtureContext
                - FeatureContext
                - DefaultContext
                - RegisterContext
```

Hopefully this is what you need.

Comment: This is the default structure suggested in sensio documentation.  I do prefer to have a different structure though.  I did figure it out now though - I'll post a self-answer with that info.